# how to give different text color for each item of listview in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have list of string which is getting assigned to the listview in xamarin forms as in below code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("A");
list.Add("B");
list.Add("C");
list.Add("D");

var listview = new ListView(); 

listview.ItemsSource = list;

Content = listview;
```

How to show all the listview items text in different color? I want to show it like these:

A --> in Red color

B --> in Blue color

C --> in Green color

D --> in Yellow color

Answer (score 6):

You can use a IValueConverter in your Binding

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        #region IValueConverter implementation

        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is string && value != null)  {
                string s = (string)value;
                switch(s){
                    case "A":
                        return Color.Red;
                    case "B":
                        return Color.Blue;
                    default:
                        return Color.Black
                }

            }
            return Color.Black;
        }

        public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

usage in xaml: 
add the namespace:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Meditation;assembly=Meditation"
```

create and add to your page StaticResources:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local: StringToColorConverter x:Key="cnvInvert"></local: StringToColorConverter >
        </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>
```

add to your binding:

```
<Label VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}">
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to Xamarin. could you please let me know where exactly i need to implement.

i have place this in same mypage.xaml.cs file.

But still it is not working.

Comment: can you post your xaml?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Srd.Jobs"
             Title="Jobs"
             BackgroundColor="#caccce">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

Comment: .xaml.cs file
`
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class mypage: ContentPage
    {

        public mypage(List<string> jobList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListView listview = new ListView();        

            listview.ItemsSource = jobList;
            Content = listview;
        }
}`

Comment: It's a bit more complex. You have start to use XAML so you should add your ListView in Xaml , create a ViewCell in Xaml and add the Label in Xaml... take a look to this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Comment: On the Label binding  you have Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}" , I think you meant TextColor