# Is it possible to make the background-colour of a Canvas field dependent on its value?

Tags: xaml

I want one datetime field's background colour to depend on its value. Like if a certain date is passed, the background changes to red. 
Is there a way to make this in XAML?

I know there is no possibility of an "if" condition/instruction, but maybe you guys found some way to implement a similar function.

```
<Canvas Canvas.Left="893" Canvas.Top="208" Height="25" Width="99" Background="red" Panel.ZIndex="-1"/>

 <assembly:FieldControl Canvas.Left="890" Canvas.Top="206" FieldControlType="DateControl" FormField="{x:Null}" Height="25" LabelColumnWidth="0" Refnr="123456789" ShowCaption="False" StateImageAlignment="Hidden" Width="106" FontSize="10" Foreground="DimGray"/>
```

this is my code so far. The Canvas-Part makes the Background go red.
I also tried to put the background property in the "FieldControl" but there it's useless.

EDIT:
After getting the information, that Data Binding could help me with this problem, i tested it like this:

```
    <TextBox  Canvas.Left="890" Canvas.Top="226" Name="Date" Width="99" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding ElementName=Date, Path = SelectedItem.Content, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" Background="{Binding ElementName=Date, Path=SelectedItem.Content}">
```

But this is not the direction, i need. Do you have maybe any suggestion, how I can use Data binding to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The concept you need to learn is **XAML Data Binding.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped. But it's still kind of difficult to find the right code. Do you have any suggestions how i can solve my problem? I just found examples for Textboxes, but that does not really fit to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the IValueConverter for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

You can check the value on binding and return the background color.

[how to give different text color for each item of listview in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281416/how-to-give-different-text-color-for-each-item-of-listview-in-xamarin-forms/43281824#43281824)